# when i assign the value of linewidth to 100 it shows the default linewidth in browser for the rectangle shape

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

[the line width of innerbox remains same for the different values in main.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPdBV.png)

main.js

```
enter code here

function init(){
    let ctx = document.querySelector('#canvas').getContext('2d');
    ctx.strokeRect(100,50,200,150);
    ctx.lineWidth = 100;
}
```

---

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Drawing on the canvas</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300">Your browser doesn't support the 
        HTML5 element canvas.
    </canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to switch the order of individual instructions

```
    ctx.strokeRect(100,50,200,150);
    ctx.lineWidth = 100;
```

to

```
    ctx.lineWidth = 100;
    ctx.strokeRect(100,50,200,150);
```

Comment: You can see an example in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/strokeRect)

Comment: Thanks for the help